# Encoding smileys in a string with mb_convert_encoding

Tags: php, mb-convert-encoding

I would like to encode smileys in PHP.

For example :

```
$string = "blah blah  blah";
mb_convert_encoding($string, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

I'm getting :

```
blah blah &#128523; blah
```

But I would like :

```
blah blah &#x1f60b; blah
```

How I can achieve that in PHP ?

Thank you !

Comment: I think it would be good if you said what do you want to encode them to and why.

Comment: What's the difference? Same number of bytes, same result.

Comment: I'm trying to compare a string sent from a form to the same string stored in a mysql database.
I'm trying to encode the string from the form to match the one in database, but I'm having a hard time with the smileys

Comment: Why are you storing HTML entities in the database? This is starting to look like an XY problem.

Comment: It's what's Wordpress or Buddypress is doing automatically

Comment: The linked question explains how to do this, but I am really curious why would anyone ever need this. Why does Wordpress do that?

Comment: Don't know too why is storred like that.. thank you for the link it's look like it's ok :)

Comment: I think I need to also check that in detail : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_encode_emoji/